# Android Phone WiFi: "Cannot Connect. Try again"

Tags: wi-fi

My new Android phone can't connect to my Wi-Fi network.

- The SSIDs are visible, not hidden.
- There is a 5ghz and a 2.4ghz network on separate SSIDs. Both have the same problem.
- The phone gives the error `Couldn't Connect. Try Again.` when the password is entered. The network entries have `Check password and try again` underneath them in Wi-Fi settings.
- The password is confirmed to be correct. It has been entered while visibly showing what the whole password is.
- Other devices can connect to the Wi-Fi access point without any problems eg. iPhone, iPad, PC with Linux, PC with Windows, Macbook, Chromecast 4k.
- The phone is brand new Poco X4 Pro.
- Network settings in Android have been reset.
- The Wi-Fi router has been reset.
- Wi-Fi bands on the router have been changed.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot the error?